# Error when starting Redis server

Tags: command-line, server, bash, redis

When I try to start redis, I get this error. I know about the port one, but what about the others? How do I fix them?

```
15418:C 14 Aug 18:57:28.924 # oO0OoO0OoO0Oo Redis is starting oO0OoO0OoO0Oo
15418:C 14 Aug 18:57:28.932 # Redis version=4.0.1, bits=64, commit=00000000, modified=0, pid=15418, just started
15418:C 14 Aug 18:57:28.933 # Warning: no config file specified, using the default config. In order to specify a config file use src/redis-server /path/to/redis.conf
15418:M 14 Aug 18:57:28.939 # You requested maxclients of 10000 requiring at least 10032 max file descriptors.
15418:M 14 Aug 18:57:28.939 # Server can't set maximum open files to 10032 because of OS error: Invalid argument.
15418:M 14 Aug 18:57:28.940 # Current maximum open files is 2048. maxclients has been reduced to 2016 to compensate for low ulimit. If you need higher maxclients increase 'ulimit -n'.
15418:M 14 Aug 18:57:28.952 # Creating Server TCP listening socket *:6379: bind: Address already in use
```

Comment: Last line says that port 6379 is already in use, so redis cannot start listening on it. Check which service is using it with `sudo netstat -tulpn | grep :6379`. Then you can stop & remove that service OR change redis config to use another port.

Comment: @bistoco I type the command and nothing happens.

Comment: what about `sudo netstat -tulpn | grep 6379`

Comment: @bistoco Still nothing, doesn't even ask me for password. Just: netstat on normal windows cmd doesn't show anything using the port 6379.

Comment: how are you trying to start redis? did you use apt to install it or from source?

Comment: From their website. @bistoco

Comment: A link should be helpful, also, did you get any output  from `sudo ps aux | grep -i redis` ?

Comment: redis.io and this is what I get:Oliver   15492  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S     2434   0:00 grep --color=auto -i redis

Comment: That means redis is not running.

Comment: i will advice you to use another port while you get into the real problem. The usual path is /etc/redis/redis.conf, and change the `port 6379` to something like `port 7002`